# How to find quartiles using histogram?

Tags: statistics

Can you suggest how can I find first and third quartiles and median after building histogram

[image]

from raw data?

[image]

I can sort the data and find the values, but still how it can be done using the chart...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The median $Q_2$ is the point such that the area under the bars each side of $Q_2$ is equal.

The lower quartile $Q_1$ is the point such that the area up to $Q_1$ is one quarter of the total area.

The upper quartile $Q_3$ is the point such that the area up to $Q_3$ is three quarters of the total area.